# Binomial distribution mixed with geometric distribution

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

Suppose X is the number of heads in 10 tosses of a fair coin. Given X=5, what is the probability that the first head occurred in the third toss?

We can assume X to a Binomial distribution with p=1/2 and n=10. Let Y=number of trails required to get one success. I presumed Y can have a negative binomial distribution with r=1, that is a geometric distribution. But how do I incorporate the relation between X and Y?

This is not a homework question, but a question that has been asked in an entrance examination in the previous years.

Comment: Since it is given that the coin is fair, the parameter for Y should be 1/2. As I've studied in the Negative Binomial Distribution, the parameter r is taken as the number of success that we want and p is the parameter of the Bernoulli distribution.

Comment: By this reasoning, p=0.5 since the coin is fair

Comment: If we take y=3, this would mean that we are counting the probability of getting r=1 success in y=3 trials, where the probability of success is p=0.5

Comment: I do not understand how to accommodate the relationship of the number of the successes in this i.e x=5

Comment: Ah, actually I had missed the information that $X=5$. That changes things. Sorry. Please disregard my original comment, I'll delete it.

Comment: Let's start over. This is actually not a question about distributions per se, but about *combinatorics*. Can you say how many ways there are to have 10 coin tosses, 5 of which are heads?

Comment: then, I would not count the ways to get 5 heads in 10 tosses, as it is given tht x=10. We only need to count ways to arrange 4 heads and 3 tails in 7 places, and that will be multiplied by 5*4*5 (that are the ways of arranging a head and two tails in the first three positions).

Comment: I don't quite understand your first sentence. You need this number as the denominator. The first half of the second sentence is correct. The second half isn't, because we *know* the arrangement of the first three tosses (what is it?).

Comment: okay, I got it. second part is wrong because this will be calculated by the combinatorics of identical objects and the ordering will not be important.

Comment: Thankyou Stephan Kolassa